# Unrecognised selector sent to instance Xcode 9

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4, xcode9, unrecognized-selector

> I have list of items to display in table view. And on clicking of each
>   item i want to trigger a method.  i-e

```
var menuItems = [LeftMenuItem]() // -> Define at top of vie controller

func populateLeftMenuData() {  // populating data in viewDidLoad
        var leftMenuItem =  LeftMenuItem(imageName: "flagIcon", cellLabel : "Home" , method : "home")
        menuItems.append(leftMenuItem)
        leftMenuItem =  LeftMenuItem(imageName: "flagIcon", cellLabel : "Logout" , method : "logout")
        menuItems.append(leftMenuItem)
    }
```

> This is how data is populating in tableview. On each row i am
>   displaying "cell label" and on clicking of cell i want to call the
>   "method".
>
> what i am doing is

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let leftMenuItem = menuItems[indexPath.row]
            perform(Selector(leftMenuItem.method!))
        }

    func logout () {
           print("logout")   
        }

    func home () {
           print("Home")  
        }
```

> But clicking on cell it saying unrecognised selector sent to an
>   instance. where as same thing is working fine for xCode 8 swift 3.

Comment: "it saying unrecognised selector sent to an instance." Show us the Whole error message. It gives clues on what went wrong. I'm not a Swift expert, but I think that Selector nomenclature have changed in Swift 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `@objc` on top of all the methods invoked with `Selector`s:

```
@objc func logout() {
    print("logout")
}

@objc func home() {
    print("Home")
}
```

In Swift 4, [`@objc` inference is very limited](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md). I doubt creating a `Selector` dynamically would be a good strategy in Swift.